# What reason is there for using service discovery instead of Kubernetes internal dns

Tags: kubernetes, service-discovery

What is the reasoning for using service discovery like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/discovery.html) instead of [Kubernetes internal DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/), like `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`? I am wondering because I am starting on a fairly large project and want to make sure I'm not setting myself up for failure using the build in Kubernetes DNS.

Comment: I dont really understand this question , k8s internal DNS is pluggable and is a form of service discovery  itself

Comment: I'm just curious what reason there would be to use something like Consul over the built in service discovery.

Comment: I dont think so , i dont think is there any reason to use consol instead of built in service discoery and etcd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service discovery by DNS name itself (inside the cluster) is somehow similar.

Other technologies are adding more functionality to the stack like: Encrypted Traffic, Connection Authorization, Proxy Sidecars, etc

You can take a look here: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/consul-1-2-service-mesh as an example.

Those frameworks will help reduce code on each container (example: retry/circuit breaker) by adding this 'plumbling' at the service level.

--M